# Kendo Angular 2 - Combobox and Dropdownlist

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Having trouble getting these 2 controls' demos to work as of the posting date. All the other controls seem to work...

Comment: Please add more information to your question. What have you tried so far? Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes, we need more information on the error, how you got it, etc...

Answer (score 4):

There was a problem in the kendo-angular-dropdowns package that has been resolved. The [online examples](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/) are now running correctly.

The problem was caused by a a change in the [dropdowns common module](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common) that renamed its entry point for consistency with other packages. Keep in mind that any existing SystemJS configurations that mention the old entry point need to be updated, from

```
  '@telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common': {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      main: "./dist/npm/js/bundle.js"
  },
```

to

```
  '@telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common': {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      main: "./dist/npm/js/main.js"
  },
```

... for both the kendo-dropdowns-common and kendo-popup-common packages.

Comment: Actually the examples online are still broken, it looks like there is an XHR error on the Tsconfig.json file

Comment: Working fine now =)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's coming from the Telerik team, this morning the DropDownsModule breaks. It's even broken on their documentation WebSite :

Documentation Link with broken ComboBox : http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/

GitHub issue Opened : https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/24

The issue is coming from the ComboBox component which has a bad link reference to their @telerik package, so unless you manually change the link in the ComboBox component in the @progress package, you have to wait for the fix from the Telerik Team.

Comment: As related in the referenced [Github issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/24), my attempts to install the `@progress/kendo-dropdowns-common` package result in an error.